# MoveClip intersection Shape

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is it posible in flash that the "red dot" is a move clip but the shapes leaves as the shapes then get text message you are on the shape nr.1 or nr.2 based on where is red dot

Is there way to get instance to the drawn shape to not converting to the move clip

Comment: Please describe your question better, as it makes no sense to me.

Comment: This function doesnt work because it makes big rectangle around shape but the shape is not a rectangle    

    if(Star.getRect(this).intersects(shape.getRect(this)))
    {
        trace("intersects")
    }

Comment: Don't understand anything. Try to describe it better.